# (Un)able to create bootable USB disk with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 installation DVD

Tags: linux, centos, redhat

I'm trying to create bootable USB disk with Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 installation DVD:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$ sudo dd if=rhel-workstation-6.5-x86_64-dvd.iso of=/dev/sdc
[sudo] password for alexus: 
8753152+0 records in
8753152+0 records out
4481613824 bytes (4.5 GB) copied, 2008.5 s, 2.2 MB/s
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$
```

I'm able to boot and install without any issues, now I want to repeat same thing w/ CentOS and/or Scientific Linux (both based off of REDHAT):

I've tried repeating same steps but replacing one ISO with another:

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$ sudo dd if=CentOS-6.4-x86_64-bin-DVD1.iso of=/dev/sdc
[sudo] password for alexus: 
8502692+0 records in
8502692+0 records out
4353378304 bytes (4.4 GB) copied, 1947.45 s, 2.2 MB/s
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$
```

and

```
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$ sudo dd if=SL-64-x86_64-2013-03-18-Install-DVD.iso of=/dev/sdc
[sudo] password for alexus: 
8481952+0 records in
8481952+0 records out
4342759424 bytes (4.3 GB) copied, 1936.24 s, 2.2 MB/s
[alexus@wcmisdlin02 Downloads]$
```

I'm not sure why but I'm *NOT* able to boot of USB anymore..

What am I doing wrong? Please advise.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this script successfully: https://git.fedorahosted.org/cgit/livecd/tree/tools/livecd-iso-to-disk.sh

Comment: I just tried it w/ SL and it worked w/out any issues) thank you!